# Merging and adding multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have a dictionary for each state in the continental US. Each has a key-value pair that I have to ultimately merge and add into a single key-value pair. It looks like this:

Indiana = {Year:2018, Total:102
Year:2017, Total: 84....}

Alabama = {Year:2018, Total: 115
Year: 2017, Total:116....}

Colorado = {Year:2018, Total: 71
Year:2017, Total: 76....}

What I want is to merge the dictionaries like this:

Continentals = {Year:2018, Total: 102+115+71
Year: 2017, Total: 84+116+76.....}

Is there a way to merge all these dictionaries into one dictionary while also summing the totals for each year together?

Comment: Are you sure the keys "Year" and "Total" are present multiple times in each dict?

Comment: Does your data have to be in this structure?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries you've provided would overwrite their own values with each entry. You would need to rearrange your dictionary structure to be closer to:

```
indiana = {2018: total_value, 2017: total_value}
alabama = {2018: total_value, 2017: total_value}
...
```

This way you could simply loop through your list of state dicts and update a new dict as you iterate.

```
continentals = {}
for state in list_of_states:
    for year, total_value in state.items():
        continentals[year] = continentals.get(year, 0) + total_value
```

Comment: We aren't allowed to alter the dictionaries. Is there any way to do with without altering them?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure the dictionaries would work as you've presented them, is there a mistake in your presentation?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jesse's structure proposition, you can even do this with a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

indiana = {2018: total_value, 2017: total_value}
alabama = {2018: total_value, 2017: total_value}

c = Counter()
for d in[indiana, alabama]:
    c.update(d)
```